# Skip non editable columns in datagrid moving arrow keys in flex

Tags: flex3

How can I skip selecting the non editable datagrid columns while moving with arrow keys. While moving between the datagrid cells, if a datagrid column is non editable I need to skip the selection to next editable column.

Please help.

Thanks,
Rejeev.

Answer (score -1):

you need override the key event handler function, and check for data of row to determine your logic there.

all other standard logic is here http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_11.html